# Passing in two different JSON objects FromBody to a controller

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

I have two JSON objects that I need to pass in to an endpoint of my MVC .net core controller.  Here is the signature for the API end point:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<FileTransLationAccepted>> GetFileText([FromBody]FileInformation fileInfo, [FromBody]FileUpload busMessage)
    {

        //Call the processing file here.  Get the ID from the JSON passed in for file download
        return await _fileDownload.DownloadFile(fileInfo, busMessage);

    }
```

Here are the two JSON objects (Models I have to pass in):

```
 public class FileUpload
{
    public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
}

public class Metadata
{
    public string[] caseNumbers { get; set; }
    public string[] tagValueIds { get; set; }
    public Textualtag[] textualTags { get; set; }
}

public class Textualtag
{
    public string tagCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string[] textValues { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the other:

```
 public class FileInformation
{
    public string CompanyId{ get; set; }
    public string FileId { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileURL { get; set; }

}
```

Is it possible to pass in both JSON files in the body without having to make two calls?  I have tried removing the [FromBody] attribute but keep getting MVC errors:

> [method] has more than one parameter that was specified or inferred as bound from request body.  Only one parameter per action may be bound from body.

So will I need to combine the two JSON objects into one larger JSON or is there a way to pass in the two objects in one call?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't google it to be sure, but I'm about 90% positive that you only get one `FromBody`. It might be best to just combine them:

```
public class Combined
{
    public FileInformation fileInformation{ get; set; }
    public FileUpload fileUpload{ get; set; }
}
```

Afterthought:  Found this...
[Multiple types [FromBody] on same method .net core web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48082324/multiple-types-frombody-on-same-method-net-core-web-api/48121385)