# Getting multiple types of json object in post method in asp.net-mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to c#. I have to modify an existing post method which receives a particular entity in the post body like below.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("{Name}/{entityName}/")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddData([FromRoute]string Name, [FromRoute]string entityName, [FromBody]Entity1 entity1)
{}
```

So far this method was just being used to post entities of type `Entity1` which is fetched using `[FromBody]`. Now I have to use the same method to fetch another entity of type `Entity2` from the body of the post request.

How can I do this without creating a new function and make sure that the route works for both `Entity1` and `Entity2` ?

Comment: Maybe [some of these comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48082324/multiple-types-frombody-on-same-method-net-core-web-api) on another post could help you out?